# Return List<string[]> and not string[][]

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that should return a list of string arrays:

```
[OperationContract]
List<string[]> ArticleSearch(int SearchField, string SearchValueMin,
           string SearchValueMax, IEnumerable<string> Fields);
```

I know that I can change the deserialization of lists from `System.Array` to `System.Collections.Generic.List` but it's useless to me because I either get `string[][]` (jagged array) or `List<List<string>>` (List of List of string) as return type. I need `List<string[]>`.

My question is; is it possible to configure this somewhere or do I have to change the `Reference.cs` file by hand, after every update?

Comment: Getting a `List<string[]>` from a `string[][]` is easy with [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.linq.aspx). `var list = jaggedArray.ToList();`.

Comment: This works for me, thank you. Where can I set the question as solved?

Comment: This was just a comment. I think the real answer (which deserves all the credit) is Damiths.

Comment: I made some changes to your question and changed one major thing: `List<List<string[]>>` - I removed the `[]` since you described it as List of List of string. I hope I interpreted that correctly.

Comment: Yes thank you, was my fault.

Comment: Btw. if you're not adding/removing stuff, for example you're just reading/looping over the result, then there is no real difference between `string[][]`, `List<string[]>` or `List<List<string>>`. You'll always have `foreach(var outer in list) { foreach(var inner in outer) { // ... } }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally collections types are returns as Arrays but you can change this behavior by configuring service reference as below.

select your service reference and go to **Configure Service Reference**...

In the Collection Type drop-down, select the type `System.Collections.Generic.List`

[image]

since you have return type as `List<string[]>` after above change you will receive `List<List<string>>`

So you can't have Array of List or List of Arrays at ones.

For your requirement you can convert array to List or List to array as Corak commented.

Comment: When i do this I got a List<List<string>>. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you can create a [DataContract] class with a List property and make your [OperationContract] return that object. at that point when you attached yourself to the WCF service from any .NET project it will be able to see the property as List.

But this is really not a good way to do it if it's just to receive List on the client side. @Corak comment to your post is the best way to do this. Don't forget other languages can read your service too and in the end all they see is XML (or json if you change default return type) .NET is just intepreting the XML to be a "Loadable" into a known object.

Comment: Yes, I use now Corak's method. Because the service is also used by a java&coldfusion client, since today. Return types have to be arrays. Lists are afaik only .net componentes.

Comment: Well List in .NET is just another IEnumerable<T>. Im pretty sure similar object exist in Java. You could change the output to JSON which will reduce in size the data sent and receive and will even simplify all (other than .NET) languages. Like if you plan using Java for android app using JSON over XML standard return you will save precious bandwidth on the person cellphone plan :). If your interested here a good link for JSON-JAVA [Google JSON sample](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Comment: Thank you. That's very useful, because I need the service for mobile apps (Android, iOS, Win-Phone) in later time. I'll propose this to my superior. Fortunately, I'm not the person that has to code the apps :D. The service is challenging enought for me...